# How to hide a parameter in Cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I want to hide a PowerShell Cmdlet parameter from user. Is there any way to do this in C#?

I want to use this parameter within my code to trigger the same cmdlet with the hidden parameter.

I use PowerShell 2.0.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you mark the property as `internal`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PowerShell 4.0 you can hide a parameter using the [ParameterAttribute.DontShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.parameterattribute.dontshow%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property. That said, the parameter is hidden only from tab completion ([PowerShell Magazine tip](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/07/29/pstip-hiding-parameters-from-tab-completion)).

Comment: This isn't working for me on C# parameters.   `[Parameter(DontShow=true)]` has no affect on the intellisence. Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a way to hide the parameter (e.g. from Get-Help) you can "hide" it in plain sight by using a common parameter that it's unlikely a user would ever specify, like -OutBuffer 0, and test for the presence of that in PSBoundParameters.