# How to hide a parameter from Get-Help (not just tab completion) in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I've searched around, and I can't find a straight answer of 'no', but also no straight answer of yes either.

What I already know:

- `[Parameter(DontShow)]` only affects tab completion
- [One suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19804080) was to use a Common Parameter and test for it's existence in `$PSBoundParameters` - while technically viable, this has the side-effect of not having the name that I want for it.
- Another suggestion was to hide it within another param as an Alias, but that suits deprecation more.

The scenario I have is having a parameter that shouldn't be used by any 3rd Party, but is used by companion scripts

example:

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]param(
  [switch]$VisibleSwitch,
  [switch]$HiddenSwitch ### This switch should not be visible to human-beings.
)
#...
if( $HiddenSwitch) {
  #do something
  return
}
#...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fear that there is **no good solution** as of PowerShell 7.2, but the **closest approximation** of what you want is probably the following:

- Define a proxy parameter whose name signals that it isn't to be used directly.
- Declare this parameter with both the `DontShow` and `ValueFromRemainingArguments` [`[Parameter()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute)properties.
- Manually check the argument(s) bound to the proxy parameter to look for the "hidden" parameter.

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
param(
  [switch] $Switch
  ,
  [Parameter(DontShow, ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
  ${(ignore)}
)

# Examine the quasi-hidden parameter value 
# for containing the switch name of interest.
$HiddenSwitch = ${(ignore)}.Count -eq 1 -and ${(ignore)}[0] -eq '-HiddenSwitch'

# Make sure that no unexpected arguments were passed.
if (-not $HiddenSwitch -and ${(ignore)}.Count -gt 0) { throw "Unexpected arguments specified: ${(ignore)}"}

# Output what switches were passed.
[pscustomobject] @{
  '-Switch' = $Switch
  '-HiddenSwitch' = $HiddenSwitch
}
```

Note:

- This won't prevent the proxy parameter from showing up in the syntax diagram (e.g. with `-?`) - it'll show as `[-(ignore) <Object>]` - but it won't reveal the true parameter name.

  - [GitHub issue #7868](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7868) asks for an official way to hide parameters from syntax diagrams, in the context of no longer showing *obsolete* (deprecated) parameters.
- Strictly speaking, you'd also have to check `${(ignore)}` for the (rarely used) syntax that allows explicitly passing a *Boolean* to the switch (e.g., `-HiddenSwitch:$true`), but I've omitted that for brevity in the code above.
- Similarly, more work would be required to support passing an unambiguous *prefix* of the hidden parameter name (e.g., `-Hidden`).

---

**If not having an extra parameter show up in the syntax diagram is paramount**, an - also suboptimal - alternative is to use a "private" variable with an obscure name, say `$__HiddenSwitch`, that the caller must set in order to emulate a `-HiddenSwitch` parameter, and which the callee (your script/function) removes after checking it.

Note that if the callee is defined in a *module*, extra effort is required to access the caller's scope.

Comment: Thank you @mklement0 ! Especially for the GitHub issue and detailed walk through of the proposed workaround (and thanks for the typo fix ).

Comment: To add, I already have a `ValueFromRemainingArguments` parameter, so I might as well use that - this way not even an `(ignore)` would show up.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @Lockszmith; my pleasure. Re `ValueFromRemainingArguments` parameter: makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another possible approach where the extra param will just be ignored if the function is called from the command line.

```
Function Test-Parm {

  Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
      [Int] $Value,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
      [String] $FromCode

  )

  $Calledby = $($MyInvocation).ScriptName
  

  If ($CalledBy.Length -eq 0) {
    "Called from Command Line"
  }
  Else { "Called from Code" }
  
}
```

Results:

```
PSv7>..\Test\Test-HideParam.ps1
Called from Code
PSv7>Test-Parm -Value 3 -FromCode "NO"
Called from Command Line
PSv7>
```

HTH

Comment: Not what I asked for, but will be added to my arsenal of patterns. Thanks!